# Count day of week occurances

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a list of members of a club together with datetime that they attended the club. They can attend the club several times in a single day. I need to know how many Sundays did each member attend over a given period (regardless how many times within a single Sunday). I have a table that lists each attendance, made up of member number and the attendance datetime.

Eg In this example 13/1 and 20/1 are Sundays

```
MEMBER                 ATTENDANCE

12345                  13/1/13 09:00

12345                  13/1/13 15:00

12345                  14/1/13 08:00

56789                  13/1/13 10:00

56789                  13/1/13 15:00

56789                  13/1/13 21:00

56789                  14/1/13 10:00

56789                  20/1/13 09:00

24680                  14/1/13 08:00

24680                  15/1/13 07:00
```

Ideally I would like to see this returned:

```
MEMBER                 # OF SUNDAYS

12345                  1

56789                  2

24680                  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
select Member,
       count(distinct dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, Attendance), 0)) as NumberOfSundays
from t
where datepart(dw, Attendance)  = 6  
group by Member ;
```

The complicated count is really doing:

```
count(distinct cast(Attendance as date))
```

but the `date` data type is not supported in SQL Server 2005.

EDIT:

Instead of `datepart(dw, Attendance) = 6`, you can use `datename(dw, Attendance) = 'Sunday'`.

Comment: Awesome. The others were counting the same day multiple times but this is only counting each day once which is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Is `6` the constant for `Sunday`? That's correct? What language is set?

Comment: The 'datename(dw, Attendance) = 'Sunday'' is correct. The 'datepart(dw, Attendance) = 6' doesn't return the right amount in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT MEMBER,
 SUM(CASE DATENAME(dw,ATTENDANCE) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [# OF SUNDAYS]
FROM   MemberTable
WHERE  ATTENDANCE between [YourStartDateAndTime] AND [YourEndDateAndTime] -- replace [YourStartDateAndTime] AND [YourEndDateAndTime] with your value or variable
GROUP BY MEMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this example, it may work also:

```
select Member
     , count( case when datepart( dw, Attendance ) = 6 then 1 else 0 end ) NumberOfSundays
  from YourTable
 where Attendance between '2013-01-13' and '2013-01-20'
 group by Member
```

Avoid use functions on your `where` clause that'll modify the original value of the field. By doing this, SQL Server will create an execution plan using a Table Scan, ignoring any index that would speed up your query!